# ¿La estructura «pueblo a pueblo» y otras semejantes van entre comas?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, redacción

Buen día.

¿Ese tipo de estructuras parecidas a «pueblo a/tras/por pueblo» tienen que ir entre comas? No he encontrado siquiera lo que son este tipo de estructuras. Si además me lo pueden indicar, les estaría agradecido sobremanera.

Para dar un poco más de contexto dejo los siguientes ejemplos:

> Lo que me gusta de la ciudad es que, **fiesta a fiesta**, la diversión nunca acaba.
> Recorrí, **pueblo a pueblo**, buscándote.
> Se va a censar, **aldea tras aldea**, el pueblo de Santa Lucía.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las estructuras:

- fiesta a fiesta
- aldea tras aldea

son circunstanciales adverbiales, en el primer caso de tiempo y en el segundo de lugar.

Me parece que la preposición "a" funciona mejor con circunstanciales de tiempo. En lugar de "pueblo a pueblo", me suena algo más natural "pueblo por pueblo".

La coma tiende a ser necesaria o al menos aconsejable cuando el circunstancial está al inicio o irrumpe en una posición no habitual dentro la frase verbal, como cuando separa el verbo del objeto. En los demás casos, diría que es opcional:

- Lo que me gusta de la ciudad es que, fiesta a fiesta, la diversión nunca acaba. (coma necesaria)
- Recorrí, pueblo por pueblo, buscándote. (coma aconsejable pero no estrictamente necesaria, porque "pueblo por pueblo" tiene "algo de objeto")
- Se va a censar, aldea tras aldea, el pueblo de Santa Lucía. (coma necesaria, porque el objeto es "el pueblo de Santa Lucía")